# how do i setup in htaccess products/item-name

Tags: .htaccess

my url currently looks like this

```
domain.com/products?product=item
```

and as for products i used

```
RewriteRule ^products$ products.php [L]
```

but i want to setup the url the first way do i keep the above rewrite or remove it if i want to use 
the first method?

this is what i tried but it wont work

```
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z])$ products.php?product=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!products\.php"
RewriteRule "^products/([^/]+).*" "products.php?product=$1" [L,QSA,PT]
```

The `[PT]` is frequently forgotten.

Comment: `[PT]` means 'pass through' and ensures that other parts of Apache (like `mod_php`) will get a look at the request.

Comment: quick question, my style sheets broke after i did that i just have them linked as /css/style.css do i need to put the domain in their as well?

Comment: also one of the items has a space in it. like products.php?product=item name for example how do i allow a space?

Comment: You should not need to include the domain the style-sheet URIs.  If their URIs begin with `/` I'm very surprised that they broke.  Can you give more detail?  As for the space, try using `[L,PT,B]` to keep the escaping intact.

Comment: i added the B and it set the server on 500 error. here is the url. http://69.231.195.173:8888/iadprint/products/flyers if you notice when you click on business card

Comment: I didn't see a 500, but I *did* see the URI getting multiple `/products/` added to it.  I've altered my answer a bit to add a `RewriteCond` that should keep that from happening.

Comment: would you have time to msg me on aim ? sarmenhb

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache 2.2.12 or later, consider using the FallbackResource directive instead. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html#fallback-resource for a more detailed description of the various options available to solve this problem.